# Shell script variable assignment with two values (regular expression)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, variables

I'm try to set a variable with two values. Here is an example:

```
letter='[[:alpha:]]'
digit='[[:digit:]]'

integer='$digit'
float='$digit.$digit'
```

The *integer* variable must appear ***one* or more times**. The variable *float* should display the first field (before the dot) ***zero* or more times**. How can I do this?

Thanks for help!

-- UPDATE --

It's very good to have the support of all of you. Below the solution that has served me:

```
letter='[[:alpha:]]'
digit='[[:digit:]]'

integer="${digit}+"
float="[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"
```

Thank you guys! :D

Comment: Use double quote instead of single quote in `integer` and `float` variables.

Comment: See the [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) section of the bash manual

Comment: thanks! single quotes doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked into bash's `expr` command (which I assume you are using) to verify which flavor of regex they use, so you may need to do something like `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[[:alpha:]]` and similar substitutions. But assume you have chosen the right value in `letter` and `digit` then this should work:

```
expr match "$string" "(${digit}*.${digit}*)"
```

or, using your `float` variable:

```
float="(${digit}*.${digit}*)"
expr match "$string" "$float"
```

Remove the parens if you just want to use the return value rather than returning the actual value matched.

Any of the following would be equivalent regexes for the integer:

```
integer="(${digit}+)"
integer="(${digit}{1,})"
integer="(${digit}${digit}*)"
```

Do be aware that there are different "flavors" of regex and in different contexts things need to be escaped where in another context they don't need it.

Comment: Note that `[a-zA-Z]` isn't necessarily equivalent to `[[:alpha:]]` — the former is all upper and lower case unaccented english characters (the ASCII set) while the latter is all upper and lower case characters _in the current locale._  The letter `ñ` can be in :alpha: but is never in a-zA-Z

Answer (score 0):

for egrep and grep -E on the bash command line:

```
float: [0-9]*\\.[0-9]+
integer: [0-9]+
```

see chart of egrep regxes at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/ for some hints but needs testing for specific situation

for perl and java:

```
float: [0-9]*?\.[0-9]+?
integer: [0-9]+?
+ matches preceding char or char class >= 1 times
* matches preceding char or char class >= 0 times
. matches any char
\. matches an uninterpreted period 
[0-9] matches the class of any digit
? forces reluctant (non-greedy) matching
```